# How to implement anonymous comparator inside stream API, more precisely sorted()?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Doctor class and collection of objects of class Doctor (cd),
each doctor has a collection of patients inside, and i need to sort doctors by number of patients and return collection of Strings with their names and number of patients, so this is my code:

```
    Collection <String> output;
    output = cd.stream()
               .sorted(new Comparator<Doctor>(){
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Doctor d1, Doctor d2){
                    return d1.getPatients().size()-d2.getPatients().size();}})
            .map(String.format("%d : %s %s", d->d.getPatients().size, d.getName, d.getSurname))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So my question is whether the code above is correct and can it be done better without implementaion of Comparable interface? Also could you help me with String.format part of the code, something is wrong there.

Thanks

**Edit1** Sorry for uncertainty regarding String.format() the Eclipse says:

- d cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: You could use `sorted(Comparator.comparing(d -> d.getPatients().size()))`

Comment: "something is wrong there" is inadequate description of a problem

Comment: @khelwood You could post that as an answer IMO (the first comment)

Comment: Also note, in general that you shouldn't subtract ints to compare them: use `Integer.compare`, to avoid overflow (which you can't get in *this* case, because `size()` is never negative).

Comment: @AndyTurner ok, thanks, i will consider it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a handy [`comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) method in `Comparator` to save you having to manually write comparators.

You can use it like this:

```
output = cd.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(d -> d.getPatients().size()))
...
```

As Holger points out, since you are comparing an `int`, you might prefer to use [`comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) in place of `comparing`.

For the formatting part, `map` expects a function (which is what `d -> ...` means), and the arguments to `format` should just be values, not functions.

So you can do your formatting using:

```
           .map(d -> String.format("%d : %s %s", d.getPatients().size(), d.getName(), d.getSurname()))
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! That was really useful. How about string.format part?

Comment: Just for pedantic completeness, since we don't know how the collection of patients is initialized, might be worth specifying what happens if it's null (eg if a new doctor has no patients and getPatients() returns null instead of an empty collection)

Comment: @Matt Then you go find whoever wrote that code and tell them they're a bad programmer. And fix it. But I'm not going to assume things are broken in the way you describe.

Comment: @Matt Regarding the empty collection, i have an exception that handles it, so it's ok.

Comment: @khelwood Also i tried your code regarding formatting but again it's wrong, i guess because map should recieve a function. The Eclipse message is the following _Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)_

Comment: I just tried it: my code works fine, as long as your `Doctor` class has methods `getPatients()`, `getName()` and `getSurname()` .

Comment: This looks like a use case for [`comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-)…

Comment: ok, my fault i didnt put brackets () after d.size. big thanks